# Most frequent attribute for a subject not returning correct number of distinct subjects

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to write an SQL SELECT to return the most frequent TIPO_ASSEPSIA for each distinct EPISODIO in my sql server.

Well from what I've seen the SELECT technically works (ex:in an EPISODIO with 3 rows, if two of the TIPO_ASSEPSIA are the same, it will choose that attribute as the most frequent) but when I went to check the number of rows I get, I get 3822 rows. This can't possibly be right since if I count the number of distinct EPISODIO I get 3897, so there are several dozens of rows missing and I don't know why. Any ideas?

The code I am using is the following one

```
SELECT DISTINCT
F1.EPISODIO,
F1.TIPO_ASSEPSIA
FROM DWS_DM F1
WHERE
 F1.TIPO_ASSEPSIA  =
    (     SELECT t.TIPO_ASSEPSIA from
            (
            SELECT TOP 1 TIPO_ASSEPSIA , (COUNT(*)) AS freq
            FROM  DWS_DM F2
            WHERE F2. EPISODIO = F1.EPISODIO
            GROUP BY F2.TIPO_ASSEPSIA 
            ORDER BY count(TIPO_ASSEPSIA) DESC)t     
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
F1.EPISODIO,
x.TIPO_ASSEPSIA
FROM DWS_DM F1
OUTER APPLY
    (       SELECT TOP 1 r.TIPO_ASSEPSIA , (COUNT(*)) AS freq
            FROM  DWS_DM r
            WHERE r.EPISODIO = F1.EPISODIO
            GROUP BY TIPO_ASSEPSIA 
            ORDER BY count(TIPO_ASSEPSIA) DESC
    ) x
```

Comment: Thanks, it returns the correct number of rows, though I need to double check yet if it is return the most frequent properly (I assume). Honestly I never came across the OUTER APPLY expression yet.

Comment: you can put x.freq in the select as well

Comment: also, if you have ties (an episodio that has several counts of tipo that are equal, you can change the order by to be ORDER BY count(TIPO_ASSEPSIA) DESC, TIPO_ASSEPSIA DESC or ASC to get the first of them else you will get random returns.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you referring back to your `F1` alias? I think you want to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
F1.EPISODIO,
F1.TIPO_ASSEPSIA
FROM DWS_DM F1
WHERE
 F1.TIPO_ASSEPSIA  =
    (     SELECT t.TIPO_ASSEPSIA from
            (
            SELECT TOP 1 TIPO_ASSEPSIA , (COUNT(*)) AS freq
            FROM  DWS_DM
            GROUP BY TIPO_ASSEPSIA 
            ORDER BY count(TIPO_ASSEPSIA) DESC)t     
    )
```

Comment: That returns me 3233 rows

Comment: If you run just the subquery, are you getting back only one row?  If so, what happens if you replace the subquery with that value?

Comment: Yeah it only gets one row and if I replace the subquery with it I get 3233 rows. The original reason why I put the F1 in the subquery was for in each EPISODIO to get the TOP 1 row of it which should have the most frequent value.

Comment: Yes, I didn't get that part of the requirement.  Your answer is spot on.